# jQuery Getting value between a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fetching the href using:

```
$(this).attr('href');
```

But i also need to fetch the value

```
<a href="#">THIS IS WHAT I NEED</a>
```

Any ideas on this one ?, not quite sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.text()`

```
$(this).text();
```